# Can rosservice commands be used on topics

Tags: ros, rosservice, ros-kinetic, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw the following line in [this wiki tutorial on ROS services and parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams):

> rosservice has many commands that can be used on **topics**, as shown below:

I think this is a typo as rosservice commands should work on services and not topics. But as a relatively new ROS user, I would like a confirmation from more experienced users.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310080/can-rosservice-commands-be-used-on-topics/) by [holadepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38807/holadepo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I think this is a typo as rosservice commands should work on services and not topics.

yes, this is a mistake and should be corrected.

Could be copy-pasta from the `rostopic` page.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [holadepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38807/holadepo/) on 2018-12-06**:
Wow! I learnt ROS from HRWROS on edx.

I have corrected the mistake though.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-06**:
Seems that `topics` was there since at least 2009-09 ([this rev](http://wiki.ros.org/action/recall/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams?action=recall&rev=8)).

Fix [diff](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams?action=diff&rev2=65&rev1=64).